# How to clear list before loading-Bootstarp 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created list group as following :

```html
 
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   
    <title>test</title>

    <!--bootstrap scripts-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--end bootsripts-->
     </head>
     
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#s">Default</button>



          <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="s"> 
               <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" >
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                   
                   
                    <div class="row">
                    
                       <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-xl-6">
                          <h5 class="text-danger">Main Catagories</h5>    
                        <div class="list-group"style="width:100px;border:none">
          
                        <a href="#vehical" class="list-group-item list-group-flush border-bottom"  data-toggle="collapse" style="text-decoration:none">Vehical</a>
                         <a href="#property" class="list-group-item list-group-flush border-bottom" data-toggle="collapse" style="text-decoration:none">Property</a>                                                                                      
                          </div>
                         </div>

                               <div class="col-6">
                               
              <div class="list-group list-group-flush" style="width:100px;border:none" >

             <div class="list-group collapsing" id="vehical" data-toggle="collapse" style="width:100px;border:none" >
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vehical1</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vehical2</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vehical3</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vehical4</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vehical5</a>
               </div>

                            
            <div class="list-group collapsing" id="property" data-toggle="collapse" style="width:100px;border:none"> 

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Property1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Property2</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Property3</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Property4</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Property5</a>
                  </div>

                    </div>
                    
                      </div>

                          </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                      
                      

                          </div>
                          
          <!--Java Scripts-->
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <!--end of java scripts-->
                          </body>
                          
                          </html>
```

When click Main Category Sub category will display on next column.but it display as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOwuv.jpg)

I need when I click new main category button ,It shows sub category in right pannel which is related to Main Category.How ever after that when click another main category button both sub categories shows in right panel but I want shows only subcategory items related to which is click main category.I use bootstrap 4 version

Comment: Hi, please clarify what do you want to do, which is the expected result and the version you are using. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering late but I think it would be helpful for somebody else facing the same issue.
Actually you were missing some attributes needed to do the tabbing on the list-group. Check the below code snippet to get the idea.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>test</title>

    <!--bootstrap scripts-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!--end bootsripts-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-default"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-target="#s"
    >
      Default
    </button>

    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="s">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-xl-4">
                <h5 class="text-danger">Main Catagories</h5>
                <div class="list-group" style="width: 100px; border: none">
                  <a
                    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"
                    id="list-vehicle-list"
                    data-toggle="list"
                    href="#list-vehicle"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="vehicle"
                    >Vehicle</a
                  >
                  <a
                    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                    id="list-property-list"
                    data-toggle="list"
                    href="#list-property"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="property"
                    >Property</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                  <div
                    class="tab-pane fade show active"
                    id="list-vehicle"
                    role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="list-vehicle-list"
                  >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Vehical1</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Vehical2</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Vehical3</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Vehical4</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Vehical5</a
                    >
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="tab-pane fade"
                    id="list-property"
                    role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="list-property-list"
                  >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Property1</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Property2</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Property3</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Property4</a
                    >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                      >Property5</a
                    >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Java Scripts-->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!--end of java scripts-->
  </body>
</html>
```